# Indirect Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $x_1 , x_2 , x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that one of the $x_i$ must be greater than or equal to the average $\frac13 (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)$.

I don't really understand how one would start out proving that this works. Would this be a contradiction?

Comment: What did you mean by $1\ (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)$?

Comment: I changed it to what I think OP meant.

Comment: What happens if they are all less than the average?

Answer (score 7):

Suppose not then $x_i < \frac{x_1 +x_2+x_3}{3}$ for all $i \in \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$. Then summing these 3 inequalities for i=1,2,3 we get $x_1+x_2+x_3 < x_1+x_2+x_3$. Which is a contradiction.